# Regex, match anything in php (\r|\n|.)*

Tags: php, regex

I have a massive string containing various segments of text. Part of the way through these strings there are two equals signs '`==`'.

I want to match '`{{Description`' if it is after there equals signs.

The way I had planned it was `'/==(\r|\n|.)*\{\{Description/i'`

But this causes a SEGFAULT when running the regex.

How else can I build a regex to match the above without having `(\r|\n|.)*` ?

Comment: To start off `{{` need to be escaped so it is `\{\{`

Comment: Sorry, yes the are escaped in my code but I didnt add the code tags and therefore the backslashes did not appear

Comment: Segfaulting looks like there is heavy bracktracking on the run. I suggest you look into [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `.*` will work if you add the `s` modifier. Also, `{` has a special meaning (introduces a numeric quantifier) so it should be escaped. Finally, `*` should probably be made lazy, otherwise it will look for the LAST appearance of `{{Description`

```
/==.*?\{\{Description/is
```